# Is adsense banning websites that have chat?

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, chat

Based on [this discussion](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/LX5A8erxpWc) it seems that Chat sites are no longer allowed to host adsense adverts. 
I have a website that is predominantly content, but chat is still a very important part of my site. I'd love to be able to keep it and still earn money.

**QUESTIONS**

- Can anyone confirm that adsense is not allowed on sites that have chat?
- If it is partly true, what is compliant with the adsense TOS and what is not? For instance, is having a chat page with no advertising on that chat page ok?
- What adsense alternatives are there that **allow a website to advertise and to have chat scripts**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is a difference between a chat site and a site with chat.** Many legitimate sites have chat features for customers contact customer service, support, or even each other. As long as the content of chats is not publicly accessible you have a site *with* chat. If chats are visible to all -  hence crawlable - you have a chat site.

Regardless of chat or not, Google does not like its ads next to certain type of contents. In the case of a largely static site, they can keep track and the mediapartner crawler probably flags them if a change adds some terms they do not like.

For this reason I suspect you can still use AdSense on portions of a site which feature their own non-chat content. Even if another part of the page may have a chat box. As long as its out of the way from the AdSense ads, you are probably OK. However, I would check with Google and use your AdSense account to send them a message about it.

Answer (score 2):

The huge problem with chat sites is the problem of the topics being discussed in them and one of the many reasons why Google is very vague on the area and I have personally heard of sites having there adsense accounts disabled, sadly Google is pretty slack when it comes to picking and choosing which sites should not be active in their adsense scheme as legit and clean sites often do get removed from their system from no fault of their own while many sites that shouldn't have accounts carry on trading.

From what I believe and have read is that you are allowed adsense adverts on chat sites (must not be on topic of their banned topics) but your not allowed to have them within `'chat containers'` and having those on the sidebar should be fine.

My advice would be to email them and provide them with the details, take screen shots of where you plan to place the advert and get an Adsense rep clarify this issue for you, least then if they do disable you at a later date they should allow release of the funds due. It's worth noting there are many other advertising companies that you can consider.

I know this answer is pretty vague but some topics on Advertising while using adsense you will find many vague areas. I know some chat sites that use Adsense, but this doesn't mean that they will not close you account as I've said they pick and choose depending which moderator reviews the account and I can only assume their own guidelines they follow are very vague and create these grey areas.